# HTML Templates -- php?

Tags: php, html, templates, templating

So, I'm making a site about WWI as a school assignment, and I want this to appear in every document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>1914</title>
    <script src="modernizr-1.5.js"></script>
    <link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <header>
    <img src="images/banner.png" alt="World War I" style="border: none"/>
    <nav>
        <ul>
        <a href="index.htm"><li><span>Home</span></li></a>
        <a href="1914.htm"><li><span>1914</span></li></a>
        <a href="1915.htm"><li><span>1915</span></li></a>
        <a href="1916.htm"><li><span>1916</span></li></a>
        <a href="1917.htm"><li><span>1917</span></li></a>
        <a href="1918.htm"><li><span>1918</span></li></a>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </header>
    <section>
    <article>
    <br style="clear: both" />
    </article>
    <aside>
    </aside>
    </section>
    <footer style="font-weight: bold; letter-spacing: .1em">
    <a href="citations.htm">Citations</a> &bull;
    <a href="about.htm">About</a>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I think it's kind of stupid to copy-paste all this into each document, and painstakingly go in and change each page separately if I just want to change one word or tag.  Is there a way I can put this in template.htm (or something similar) and have php or javascript code take this and insert everything from the requested file inside of the `<article>` tag?  I don't know a lot of php, so this is probably a piece of cake for you gurus, but I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Hi Code Monkey,

What Software are you using to make your project?  The only reason I ask is that most HTML editors come with a feature called 'Snippets' which allows you to add any code you use regularly and when you want to use the code you usually just have to select one option form a menu. Dreamweaver, PHP Designer, PHP Storm, PHPEd and most others have this feature. If you let me know what your using I'll try and steer you in the right direction

Comment: Have a look at the MVC design pattern

Comment: @AronDraper Thanks, but I'm not looking for an IDE solution, I'm looking for a piece of code I can put in my document.

Comment: I wish I could downvote comments... MVC != 42... :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Using php includes:

Save this as top.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
<script src="modernizr-1.5.js"></script>
<link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<header>
<img src="images/banner.png" alt="World War I" style="border: none"/>
<nav>
    <ul>
    <a href="index.htm"><li><span>Home</span></li></a>
    <a href="1914.htm"><li><span>1914</span></li></a>
    <a href="1915.htm"><li><span>1915</span></li></a>
    <a href="1916.htm"><li><span>1916</span></li></a>
    <a href="1917.htm"><li><span>1917</span></li></a>
    <a href="1918.htm"><li><span>1918</span></li></a>
    </ul>
</nav>
</header>
<section>
```

Save this as bottom.php

```
<aside>
</aside>
</section>
<footer style="font-weight: bold; letter-spacing: .1em">
<a href="citations.htm">Citations</a> &bull;
<a href="about.htm">About</a>
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then your individual pages would be like this:

```
<?php $title = '1914'; include("top.php");?>
//This would be where you would make the changes that need to be made on each page.

<article>
<br style="clear: both" />
</article>

<?php include("bottom.php");?>
```

Comment: the individual pages would still be saved as htm, or php?

Comment: They'd be saved as php, I just realized there was an error in the top template. Fixed.

Comment: Do you need to declare $title before the include?

Comment: You need to have declared $title before the include.

Comment: Yeah, you're both correct, not sure what I was thinking to be honest. Answer corrected, thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You could consider one of these popular template engines :

- **[Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)** (becoming outdated)
- **[Latte](https://github.com/nette/latte)** (used mostly by the **[Nette](http://nette.org/)** community)
- **[Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation)** (used mostly by the **[Symfony](http://symfony.com/)** community)
- **[Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/)** (official implementations of this templating engine exist in more than two dozen proramming/scripting languages)

I tend to favor **[Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/)**, mostly because it has **[an official JS version](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)**,  **[an official Ruby version](https://github.com/defunkt/mustache)**, **[an official Java version](https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java)**, etc. It allows you to use the same templates frontend and backend, which is very useful for widgets that are first rendered in background and rerendered in foreground at updates.

Answer (score 3):

Put the content in a file **abc.php**

and then add this to each page you want the desired content in :

```
<?php
include("abc.php");
?>
```

So if your code is :

```
<nav>
        <ul>
        <a href="index.htm"><li><span>Home</span></li></a>
        <a href="1914.htm"><li><span>1914</span></li></a>
        <a href="1915.htm"><li><span>1915</span></li></a>
        <a href="1916.htm"><li><span>1916</span></li></a>
        <a href="1917.htm"><li><span>1917</span></li></a>
        <a href="1918.htm"><li><span>1918</span></li></a>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </header>
    <section>
    <article>
    <br style="clear: both" />
    </article>
    <aside>
    </aside>
    </section>
```

And you want the part inside `<nav>` to be repeated in each page, you can put the content between `<nav>` and `</nav>` (including the tags) inside **abc.php** and include **abc.php** in your file like this :

```
<?php
    include("abc.php");
?>
    </header>
    <section>
    <article>
    <br style="clear: both" />
    </article>
    <aside>
    </aside>
    </section>
```

Comment: This wont work because even tough the code will be included in each page if you want to edit just one line in each page you wouldn't be able to see the code to do so.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.  If I just copy/paste what I have into php, wouldn't that just add the page content to the end of the php content?  The real question:  how can I insert what I have in the document inside of the `<article>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

Create the template file as a single file, exactly you have it already, but printing PHP variables in the places where you want content.

eg:

```
....
<article>
<?php print $mainContent; ?>
</article>
....
```

Then write a PHP function as follows:

```
<?php
function insertContentIntoTemplate($mainContent) {
    require_once('/path/to/template.php');
}
?>
```

Now you can load your page content into the template simply by calling the function and passing the content into it for each page.

So, for example, 1914.php could look like this:

```
<?php
require_once('/path/to/insertFunction.php');

//the text could be loaded from a DB, or from another file, or just as a plain string like this:
$text = "The year was 1914, and the war was just starting.";

insertContentIntoTemplate($text);

?>
```

Congratulations. You now have a working (albeit very simple) template system. Add more variables / placeholders to your template as required.