# How to use HTML as template in PHP?

Tags: php, html, parsing, templates

I want to use html as a template and filling the data with PHP. If I've some html this way

```
<h1>${heading-1}</h1>
<p>${paragraph}</p>
```

I want to replace the template tags with the matching value in my PHP array. If I've an array of all possible matches

```
$possible_matches = array(
  'heading-1'=> 'You can\'t do anything',
  'paragraph' => 'Unless you show your code which you don\'t have so be ready for down votes'
);
// what now?
```

And it changes the html like

```
<h1>You can't do anything</h1>
<p>Unless you show your code which you don't have so be ready for down votes</p>
```

How can I achieve this? Should I use regex?

Comment: please check this how create templates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071784/html-templates-php

Comment: Did you really read the question or just assumed it through the title ?

Comment: Actually, @Tegito123 's suggestion is spot on.  Don't parse HTML with regex (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 0):

you can use foreach loop and str_replace like this

```
$html = '<h1>${heading-1}</h1>
<p>${paragraph}</p>';
$possible_matches = array(
  'heading-1'=> 'You can\'t do anything',
  'paragraph' => 'Unless you show your code which you don\'t have so be ready for down votes'
);
foreach($possible_matches as $key=> $value){
$html = str_replace('${'.$key.'}',$value,$html);
}
echo $html;
```

and if html template included in external file you can use file_get_contents to put the html in variable $html